# React: Avoid renders just left one when data already loaded in array

Tags: reactjs, react-native

My scenario is like this I have two tabs and what I want is that when I loaded my first tab is by default selected I save my items in an array and then I click my second tab but when i got back my items in the first tab pass for the render function again, is this necessary? Is there a way that can not to happen this render if i have my items in the array I don't know if react has to render again because it is like that how it works or there is way to prevent that second render. Thank you.

Comment: perhaps you need to override componentShouldUpdate()

Comment: Let me see if I understand this: you have a tab view component, that has different child views, and you want the child views to state rendered  while you switch the tab view to another child view, correct?

Comment: @GarrettMotzner Thats right. The thing is that for make the tab work i have to use state for manage the change of the tab, and that will always trigger re render whenever I change tab right?

Comment: Depends on how you "change" the active tab. If you render a different component when the  active tab changes, then yes, that would cause a re-render. also, if you had content with a `key` prop that was tied to the active tab, that would cause that component to re-render as well (this can be a useful trick sometimes). However, if all that changes is the props passed to the tab content, that may not always re-render the entire tab (depending on what type of component render lifecycle you have). It may change only sub-components.

Comment: Additionally, there are ways to keep a component rendered when you change the tab, such as hiding the visibility of the component but leaving it in the DOM. That is a somewhat common trick, although less common in react. I also suspect that there might be ways to render a component "offscreen" into a DOM that isn't part of the active document, and then add that component to the main document (and also detach it). However, I've never done that, and you probably don't need to be that clever. If you did, I'd start by looking at how react animation libraries are implemented...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the call to `render()` in that case, you can add the lifecycle method `shouldComponentUpdate()` and return false. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)

Comment: If i have put it on false it does not render the first time, I just need the first time